# SQL Alchemy like/regex query for zero or more characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, flask, sqlalchemy

I have strings in rows which has the following pattern.

```
1) '"foo": [a, b, c]'
2) '"foo": [aa, c]'
3) '"foo": [aaaa]'
4) '"foo": [b, c, a]'
5) '"foo": [ba, ca, a1234aaa]'
```

I need to find the Number of rows that have the character a and only and only the character a(not aa or aaaa). [Answer is 2 rows. Row Num 1 and Row Num 4]

Logic: **a character preceded by zero or one [space] and ends with zero or one [comma]**

I have done:

```
likestr = '"foo": [%a%]'
query = db.session.query(X).filter(X.Y.like('%'+likestr+'%'))
```

Obviously, this returns count as 4, while the right answer is 2 How would my query look in regular expressions?

Comment: Your question is a little self-conflicting. Doesn't 2 contain 'aa'??

Comment: @StevenXu I mean the number of rows matching the requirement is 2. not the 2nd row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple enough to do without regex.  The following would work ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2a58/4/0)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField like '%[a,%' 
   OR MyField like '%, a,%' 
   OR MyField like '%, a]%'
```

Or, if you want to regex ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2a58/47/0)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField REGEXP '\\[a, |, a,|, a\\]';
```

Comment: this will not be generic, as i believe we can have cases like a123 .. We just need a single a which has zero or one spaces before it and one or one commas after it.

Comment: **@Vamsi Krishna**,  I modified my answer.  Does that work better for you?

Comment: Can we have a simple reg-exp which solves this rather than ORs.. as you see i am trying the Flask sql alchemy,, and ideally it must be as generic as possible.

Comment: **@Vamsi Krishna**, I modified my answer showing how to accomplish what you are asking via regex.